# How to use Desktop Lock Screen and turn off XScreenSaver Login Screen?

Tags: linux-mint, login, cinnamon, screen-lock, xscreensaver

I am running Linux Mint 17.1, Cinnamon Desktop, Compiz, and XScreenSaver.

I want to be able to use the Desktop Lock Screen and turn off the XScreenSaver Lock Screen.

Turning off the Lock Screen in the XScreenSaver GUI deactivates all Screen Locking.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer it to pull down your menu, then pick Preferences and then Screensaver

There are a bunch of settings available, most hidden inside each saver.

But the lock settings are right there on the first screen.

---

However, your question is not clear as to what you mean by implying a difference between the desktop and the xscreen.

By definition, the screensaver is for the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Screen saver settings are now under:

`Settings > Power Manager > Security (tab)` at least for Xfce.

Change `Light Locker > Automatically lock the session` to `Never`.

Then

`Settings > Login Window > Users (tab) > Automatic Login` and put in a username.